# What tools can be used to capture Http request with full path?

Tags: rest, http

There are a number of tools one can use to capture HTTP requests for debugging purposes:

1. Request.bin
2. Hookbin
3. Puts.box

However, all of them provide a simple url such as `request.bin/axyz`. As I am testing a Rest API, I can set my base url to be `request.bin/axyz` but my request will look like

`PUT request.bin/axyz/clients/3`

and will not be matched by any of the mentioned tools. Are there useful tools?

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing testing on desktop machines, you can simply try an HTTP Proxy.

[Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) and [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) (and many more) must do the trick.

Comment: I am not, unfortunately